# How to remove space between date rows react native calendars

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRdSr.png)

how to remove space between date rows
and 2nd question how to align day names from top to left side

I want days on left side not on top

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Calendar **component can receive theme prop**. you can pass the follow:

```
theme={{ 'stylesheet.calendar.header': { header: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingLeft: 100, paddingRight: 100, marginTop: 6, alignItems: 'center' } } }}
```

or you can get help from the post : https://morioh.com/p/026cbeaeb2a3

Answer (score 0):

remove space between date rows: theme={{weekVerticalMargin:0}}
align day names from top to left side: I use dayComponent

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).